# How to format a date after emitting it with socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

After passing the time via socket.io I can no longer format it.

Lets say I have the following object.

```
let post = {
    date: new Date();
}
```

with the following sockets code.

```
socket.emit("post",post);

socket.on("post", function(data){
    // This works
    console.log(data.date);
    // This doesn't work
    console.log(data.date.getHours());
}
```

**The output**

2019-04-28T17:48:26.890Z

Uncaught TypeError: data.date.getHours is not a function

Comment: *"This doesn't work"* what is the output for that log? Also what does your log look like for `data.date` Maybe you could try `new Date(data.date).getHours()`

Comment: "Maybe try new Date(data.date).getHours()". This works.

Comment: When you used `data.date.getHours()` it wasn't formatted as a date.  It wasn't anything but a string hence the need for `new Date()` again. I am glad my suggestion has become of some help to you :)